# Lua Programming with ComputerCraft

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I have created a small program that asks for the length width and heights that you wish a mining turtle to mine. When I run it in the advanced computer though, It lets me prompt for the length, width and height but then I get an error. The error is as follows:

miner:39: attempt to index ? ( a nil value)

Here is my code:

```
term.clear()
term.setCursorPos(1,1)





write("Length:")
length = read()
print()
write("Confirm:")
ul = read()
print()

write("Width:")
width = read()
print()
write("Confirm:")
uw = read()
print()

write("Height:")
height = read()
print()
write("Confirm:")
uh = read()
print()

local totcount = ul + uw + uh
local subcount = 0




function Length()

repeat 

    turtle.dig()
    turtle.forward()
    length = length - 1
    subcount = subcount + 1

until length == 0
length = ul

end

function Width()

repeat

    turtle.dig()
    turtle.forward()
    width = width - 1
    subcount = subcount + 1

until width == 0
width = uw
end

function Height()
turtle.digDown()
turtle.down()
height = height - 1
subcount = subcount + 1
end

function Turn()

turtle.turnRight()

end



repeat

Length()
Turn()
Width()
Turn()
Length()
Turn()
Width()
Turn()
Height()

until subcount == totcount
```

Comment: Any help or comment is appreciated

Comment: You're missing `end` for the `function Length()` definition

Comment: @Schollii I have revised my code, I do not quite understand what you said about the while loop, if you can, will you post some code?

Comment: @hjpotter92  @ Schollii  I have once more revised my code, instead of while loops I used repeat loops, yet now CC is telling me that I am indexing a nil value, Please re-read my question Thank You

Comment: @Schollii Ok I figured it out!, my code was fine after my last edit I forgot to put it on the turtle lol!

Comment: OK could you please accept an answer if worked. I was posting from my phone so could not post code but I'm glad to hear your code now works. Also you should probably change your question code back to what it was because now anyone reading it has no way of knowing what issue was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look any of your functions have `end`, fix that first.  If you properly indent your code you will see this.

You also have `while count < length do` with an `else` block. AFAIK this is not valid syntax (never seen it and just checked online ref manual and wiki). It is not clear whether you meant `if count < length do`, but if really meant `while` then replacing `else` by `end` doesn't look right either. Take a closer look at that section of code.

Comment: I have revised my code, and replaced all while loops with repeat loops, please see if you know what is still wrong, I have changed the error that occurs in the question as well. Thank You for all your help.